# Design approach for controller

Tags: java, design-patterns

What is the design approach if  3 war files sharing same service and busniess logic layer.How i should use Controller here. if i am not using application server,I mean not packing into ear file.

What is the alternative for the controller?

Regards,

Raju komaturi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to keep your controller in their respective war file in the *design phase*, but your project putting these together needs to *repack* those wars into **one** common war file - which lets you map all paths in the same `web.xml`. If you're using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and its [WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) plugin it can handle this task for you.

I'm not sure exactly what you define as `Controller`, but if you're referring to *Springs*, e.g., annotated Controllers, then they can most certainly be used this way. Same with regular servlets.

Comment: @John Sjoberg: Why i have to define three controllers ,if i have to acess same service and business logic layer.What if i use handlers here.

Comment: @Raju, That's perfectly alright. The produced war-file will contain all classes and dependant jars.